# Как можно распарсить строку C#, если я создаю экземпляры Label?

Tags: c#, winforms, строки, парсер

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно распарсить строку, если я создаю экземпляры Label?
Вот конструктор:

```
public TextManager(RichTextBox rtb, Label insideTemp, Label outsideTemp, Label huMidity, Label lightLevel)
    {
        _displayWindow = rtb;
        _insideTemperature = insideTemp;
        _outsideTemperature = outsideTemp;
        _humidityLevel = huMidity;
        _lightLevel = lightLevel;
    }
```

Потом я должен распарсить входную строку, допустим - "temp1 = 25C, temp2=33, humidity = 85, light level = 57 \r";
И как работать с экземпляром не пойму, или вообще не пойму... Прошу дельного совета. Буду благодарен любому ответу.

Comment: Можно распарсить строку с помрщью разбиения на подстроки Split(','),  еще лучше использовать регулярки. Но вообще не совсем понятно что вы делаете и причем тут 'экземпляры Label'

Comment: @nick_n_a, ааа, что здесь происходит? я вообще не понимаю о чем пишете Вы и ТС.

Comment: Вы хотите занести информацию из строки вида : `"temp1 = 25C, temp2=33, humidity = 85, light level = 57 \r"` и отобразить значения в 4 соответствующих `Label`?

Comment: Требуется уточнить вопрос. Если он касается парсинга строк, то при чём тут label'ы - использовать Split и всё; если он касается label'ов, то нужно пояснить, что конкретно непонятно.

Answer (score 1):

Жуткое исполнение, но бог с ним... Вам в нужно подумать над выводом информации и рефакторинге кода. В том исполнении вопроса, которое сейчас есть, ответ звучит следующим образом:

```
string str="temp1 = 25C, temp2 = 33, humidity = 85, light level = 57 \r";
str=str.Replace(" \r", string.Empty);
string[] parsedstr=str.split(", ");
Label insideTemp= new Label();
Label outsideTemp= new Label();
Label huMidity= new Label();
Label lightLevel= new Label();

insideTemp.Text=parsedstr[0].split(" = ")[1];
outsideTemp.Text=parsedstr[1].split(" = ")[1];
huMidity.Text=parsedstr[2].split(" = ")[1];
lightLevel.Text=parsedstr[3].split(" = ")[1];
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();//хз зачем он вам.

TextManager TxtM = new TextManager(rtb, insideTemp, outsideTemp, huMidity, lightLevel)
```

Comment: Я тут все-таки сделал через регулярные выражения.  'код'  private string parse(string regExp, string input)'

Comment: Если это решило проблему - дайте ответ на свой вопрос сами и выберите его решением.